# Toyota Avalon 2006 headlight low beam height adjustment

Tags: toyota, headlight, avalon

Recently I replaced my headlight low beam Halogen bulbs with LED bulbs.

But after driving for couple days I noticed that my lights are pointing too high.

I am trying to understand what may cause an issue:
1. Either I need to adjust the height
2. Or I need to rotate/flip my bulbs 180 degree around?
Or maybe it is something else?

LED bulbs I bought: OPT7 LED Headlight Bulbs w/ Clear Arc-Beam Kit - 9006 - 60w 7,000Lm 6K Cool White CREE. Here is [amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VNBDVOC) if needed.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I could be wrong, but in the pics it looks as though there is a "**L**" and an "**R**" on the face next to the LED. You may want to check. The L/R would be as you are sitting in the driver's seat.